# Project all fields except X

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to return partial documents with DynamoDB. Instead of listing all the items I want returned using *ProjectionExpression*, it would be far easier in this case to just filter the single item I don't want returned.

i.e. below, I'd like to return everything *except* `privateItem`.

```
{
"item1" : ...,
"item2" : ...,
"privateItem" : {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this possible? I've scoured the docs to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html) it seems that you can't, you can only get either every field or a whitelist of fields (maybe that'll change in future though).

In your case I would imagine the best thing to do is to delete/filter the field you don't want after you've retrieved the document from DynamoDB.

Comment: Thanks, I came to this conclusion myself as well. There's some strange limitations to Dynamo. Not a big deal however, I just have to run a map on the response to delete the private field.